# What are the "manual" steps to upgrade a kubernetes cluster (without using kubeadm)?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-cluster

## Kubernetes Cluster Upgrades *The Hard Way*

What are the (high-level) steps required to upgrade a HA kubernetes cluster?

In the spirit of "Kubernetes the Hard Way", what are the manual steps that would form the basis of an automated process to achieve an upgrade of: 
the control plane components? 
the worker components?

The official docs assume the use of kubeadm, which is outside the scope of this question.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how your current installation looks like. If the control plane components are static pods, you need to update the yaml file in the ***/etc/kubernetes/manifests*** folder. And if it is systemctl service you need to install the latest version and reload the service.